# find a tuple in a tuple of tuples

Tags: c++, templates, stdtuple

I have a set of classes, like A, B, C and a tuple of tuples containing these classes, like this:

```
struct A {
    std::string name{"a"};
};

struct B {
    std::string name{"b"};
};

struct C {
    std::string name{"c"};
};

// only first items A(), B(), C() do matter, other are arbitrary
auto t = std::make_tuple(
    std::make_tuple(A(), 1, 2, 3),
    std::make_tuple(B(), 4, 5, 6),
    std::make_tuple(C(), 7, 8)
);
```

My target logic is to select a tuple from a container tuple by match of type of the first element. So, by example above, I want to get string 'b', when calling something like this:

```
std::string the_b = having_first_of_type<B, decltype(t)>::get().name;
```

I am trying to get a solution with templates:

```
// a template for getting first item from N-th tuple int Tuples
template <std::size_t N, typename... Tuples>
using first_of_nth = std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Tuples...>>>;

template <std::size_t N, class T, class... Tuples>
struct having_first_of_type;

template <std::size_t N, class T, class... Tuples>
struct having_first_of_type<N,
                   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, typename first_of_nth<N, Tuples...>::type>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
{
    static auto& get(const std::tuple<Tuples...>& tuple) {
        return std::get<N>(tuple);
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, class T, class... Tuples>
struct having_first_of_type<N,
                   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, typename first_of_nth<N, Tuples...>::type>::value, T>::type* = nullptr> : having_first_of_type<N-1, T, Tuples...>;

template <std::size_t N, class T, class... Tuples>
struct having_first_of_type<0, T, Tuples...> {}
```

And I can't form the specializations in the right way. For the first one (std::is_same is true) compiler says: `error: expected '>'` for position of '= nullptr'. It looks like it does not accept default value for T*, but I am confused why..

What's the error? Or, perhaps there is a better way to get what I want?

UPDATE
below are 2 working solutions: from N. Shead and @n314159 - thank you!

I forgot to mention that I tried to get it using C++14, but the solutions are for C++17.

C++17 is also OK.

Comment: `item()` should be the inner `tuple` object, or its first element, which has type `B`? You say "select a tuple from a container tuple", but then have ...`item().name` though a `std::tuple` doesn't have a `name` member.

Comment: Yes, @aschepler, your are right, of course `item()` is wrong - there should be `get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a nullptr where a tyle belongs does not make sense. You should remove that. Further I am not exactly sure, what goes wrong. We can make the whole thing a bit easier by using the `std::get` version templated on a type not an index, then we don't have to carry the N:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class Tup, bool negated = false>
using first_of = std::enable_if_t<negated ^ std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<0, Tup>, T>>;

template<class T, class= void, class... Tups>
struct first_match_impl;

template<class T, class Tup1, class... Tups> 
struct first_match_impl<T, first_of<T, Tup1>, Tup1, Tups...> {
    using type = Tup1;

    template<class FullTup>
    static Tup1& get(FullTup& t) {
        return std::get<Tup1>(t);
    }
};

template<class T, class Tup1, class... Tups>
struct first_match_impl<T, first_of<T, Tup1, true>, Tup1, Tups...>: first_match_impl<T, void, Tups...> {};

template<class T, class... Tups>
using first_match = first_match_impl<T, void, Tups...>;

template<class T, class... Tups>
auto& get_first_of(std::tuple<Tups...> &t) {
    return first_match<T, Tups...>::get(t);
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::tuple<int, float>, std::tuple<char, double>> t {{1,2.}, {'A', 4.}};
    std::cout << std::get<0>(get_first_of<char>(t)); // prints A
}
```

Note that this will not compile when you have two exactly identicall tuples in your tuple but will compile if there are different tuples with the same first element (then it will pick the first of them).

**EDIT:** This inspired me write a small library providing iterator like support for tuples. See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235784/iterating-over-a-tuple).

Comment: Cool, it works for c++17, thought I forgot to mentions that I use c++14.. But this is definitely a working solution

Comment: @atlascoder It can work for C++14 if you replace the `_t` and `_v` with the appropriate definitions, as in `template<class T, class Tup, bool negated = false>
using first_of = typename std::enable_if<negated ^ std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<0, Tup>::type, T>::value>::type;`. My solution does require C++17 though for `if constexpr`.

Comment: Yes, I see. Your solution is close to my logic, and is what I've been trying to get - thank you!

Comment: @atlascoder See my edit of my answer. I wrote a small library generalizing this.

Answer (score 2):

You've tried to give a default value in a place where the compiler expects a concrete type.

I'm assuming you want to get the whole inner tuple? 
In that case, my attempt at solving this would look something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Tuple>
constexpr bool tuple_first_type_is() {
    if constexpr (std::tuple_size_v<Tuple> == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return std::is_same_v<T, std::tuple_element_t<0, Tuple>>;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t I, typename NestedTuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) having_first_of_type_impl(NestedTuple&& nested_tuple) noexcept {
    using D = std::decay_t<NestedTuple>;
    static_assert(I < std::tuple_size_v<D>, "type not found in tuple");
    using ith_tuple = std::tuple_element_t<I, D>;

    if constexpr (tuple_first_type_is<T, ith_tuple>())
        return std::get<I>(std::forward<NestedTuple>(nested_tuple));
    else
        return having_first_of_type_impl<T, I+1>(std::forward<NestedTuple>(nested_tuple));
}

template <typename T, typename NestedTuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) having_first_of_type(NestedTuple&& nested_tuple) noexcept {
    static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<NestedTuple>> > 0, "empty tuple");
    return having_first_of_type_impl<T, 0>(std::forward<NestedTuple>(nested_tuple));
}
```

Live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa1637939a5d7d7c

I'm not 100% confident I've done everything correctly with value categories and the like, and there could well be a better way of going about this, but this is the sort of thing I would start off with.

Comment: Thank you for the solution with `constexpr if` - this is what I must be will learn! But the answer from n314159 is closer to my initial question by used logic of code.

Comment: @atlascoder Yup no worries :) I just find functions much easier to write and understand than template metaprograms, so this is what I leapt to first, but is unfortunately only really viable from C++17 in general.

Comment: Yeah, I read about `if constexpr`, and agree that it's a bit easier because of no variadic templates usage